# h:command button oncomplete action

Tags: jsf, richfaces, download

When downloading file from server if i use    **a4j:commandLink**  file download fail(mean file written to browser screen) if i use **h:commandLink** it is okay.I want to show a rich modal panel when file downloading but standard  components not have a **on complete** action  so **i cant hide modal panel after file downloaded** .How can i workaround this issue,I am using rich faces 3.3

```
  <h:commandLink value="Download"
   action="#{logSearcher.downloadFile}" 
  onclick="Richfaces.showModalPanel('ajaxLoadingModalBox',{width:450, top:200})"
                                   immediate="true" >
                          <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{log}"
                            target="#logSearcher.selectedLogLine}"   
                                    />                          
  </h:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<a4j:commandLink>` sends by default an asynchronous (ajax) request. You cannot download files using asynchronous requests. JavaScript simply does not offer facilities to turn a `XMLHttpRequest` response into a *Save As* dialog. You need to download files using a normal synchronous request. The `<h:commandLink>` does that.

Your best bet is to use the `onclick` attribute of `<h:commandLink>` to close the modal panel. If necessary with a [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout).

Comment: I am trying to find file on server connecting remote machines and file size change a lot how can i set a suitable timeout.

Comment: The speed of the *Save As* popup does not depend on the file size. It depends on the speed the HTTP response headers arrives. I'd say, one or two seconds ought to be reasonable.

Comment: I know you are answering lots of question and you are an expert  programmer but i am not :).So I am allready showing model panel onclick event.How can I hide it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use de rich:componentControl or the JS API show function (#{rich:component('mp')}.show).

http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/modalPanel.jsf?s=blueSky#