# Fire javascript event when file starts to download - when response is received

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, download

The intent is to display a wait spinner icon while the server is preparing the file for download.   In my use case I am generating a large report, this takes some time server-side before the browser's Download / Save As prompt gets invoked.  I can show the wait spinner no problem, but am having trouble finding a way to clear it.

Current relevant code:

```
<h:commandButton id="generate" value="Generate Report" type="submit" 
    action="#{bean.generateReport()}" 
    onclick="#{rich:component('waitIcon')}.start();"/>

<a4j:status id="waitIcon">
     <f:facet name="start">
       <h:graphicImage value="/images/ai.gif" alt="ai" />
    </f:facet>
</a4j:status>
```

Where `bean.generateReport()` is an action that takes 1-10secs serverside, then spits back a download response.

This is using richfaces a4j:status indicator, as it gives useful API like .start() and .stop() but it could just as well be any dom element and setting visibility.  The problem is I can't get the right event to hook on.  I need to capture something like onresponsereceived...

Solutions I've tried:

Using `a4j:commandButton` offers an `oncomplete` event, but the button generates an AJAX request, which is incapable of starting the download.  (See [h:command button oncomplete action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288803/hcommand-button-oncomplete-action))

Using a `window.timeout` function to call `.stop()` on the component.  This works on a functional level, but since the generation time swings pretty wildly between 1-10 secs, it makes the indicator kind of not reflecting reality.

Anyone have any good ideas on handling this?

Comment: Your question title is confusing. You seem rather to be interested in firing JS code when file download is finished. Can you please revise this?

Comment: Im actually interested in firing JS code when the file download starts (Response received by browser).  The event delta I am looking to display the spinner is from Request Sent -> Response Received.   Sent is easy with onclick event.  Received... not so  :)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to return to the same page wherein you conditionally render a piece of JS code which initiates the actual download.

```
<h:form>
    ...
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.prepareFileForDownload}" />
    <h:outputScript rendered="#{bean.fileReadyForDownload}">
        // Do here your thing to indicate start of download.
        window.location = '#{bean.fileDownloadURL}';
    </h:outputScript>
</h:form>
```

Another way would be to check for a cookie at intervals. You only need to generate an URL safe value as some kind of download token (`System.currentTimeMillis()` is perfectly applicable for this).

```
<h:form>
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="#{bean.token}" />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.downloadFile}" onclick="checkToken(this.form.token)" />
    <h:outputScript>
        function checkToken(token) {
            var pollDownloadStart = setInterval(function() {
                if (document.cookie.indexOf("download=" + token) > -1) {
                    document.cookie = "download=" + token + "; expires=" + new Date(0).toGMTString() + "; path=/";
                    clearInterval(pollDownloadStart);
                    // Do here your thing to indicate start of download.
                }
            }, 500);
         }
    </h:outputScript>
</h:form>
```

with this in `downloadFile()`

```
// Prepare download here.
// ...

// Once finished, set cookie and stream download to response.
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("download", token);
cookie.setPath("/");
response.addCookie(cookie);
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplistic solution would be to set the setTimeout to say 1 second to check whether the response has been received. The setTimeout will repeat until cleared.

So you could do:

```
var responseReceived, hTimer = setTimeout( function() {
    if( responseReceived ) {
        // code to stop/hide spinner here
        clearTimeout( hTimer );
    }
}, 1000 );

// responseReceived is set when the response is received
```

Alternatively, what you need is what is called a comet in programming terms. For your needs a Ajax long-poll should suite your needs best. You basically open a ajax request to the server (which is asynchronously) and the callback function does whatever you want when the server responds. Take a look at these references:

- [How do I implement basic "Long Polling"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

Comment: The getting ahold of when `responseReceived` is the real problem :)  The iframe suggestion in that comet link looks to be the most promising, however I believe I will have similar troubles trying to initiate a download via javascript/ajax through that iframe.  Will prove it out and reply...  I wish there was a more direct solution.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your point about window.timeout. In that case the comet solution is probably your best bet

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your user fills some data in a **form** then clicks the **submit** button to **POST** the data to the server which then processes it and after a while it generates a response which triggers the "Save as..." dialog window. If that is correct, the solution is to create a hidden **iframe**, then redirect the server's response to that **iframe** by setting the **target** property on the **form**, and finally hooking on the **onload** event of the **iframe**.